# html parse into DOM preformance

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor server code needs to parse html string after getting it from the web. Since many users maybe using the app at one time, a good approach is needed as to minimise overhead and response time.

**edit**
edited after the answer by Pitaj
The code needs to parse the html into dom so that it can extract elements and do other things with it, thus synchronous.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

here is what I did

```
myResponse = (function () {
  const parser = new DOMParser();

  const doc = (html) => {
    return parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/xml');
  };

  return {
    message: (html) => {
      return doc(html).select('span[blah..]').get(0).innerText;
    }
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pull it out into another Thread using [this webworker implementation for Node](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) on something similar.

It would allow the event loop to continue on since the DOM parsing would be done in another process.

This is how I'd do it with the built-in `child_process.fork()`:

```
// main file
myResponse = {
  message: (html, callback) => { // whatever callback, this is async now
    const fork = require('child_process').fork;
    const parse = fork('./parse');
    parse.on('message', (message, data) => {
      if (message === 'ready') {
        parse.send('html', html);
      } else if (message === 'data' && data) {
        callback(null, data);
      }
    });
  },
};

// `parse.js`
process.on('message', (message, data) => {
  if (message !== 'html' || !data) {
    return process.send('Error', new Error('Failed'));
  }

  const parser = new DOMParser();

  const doc = (html) => {
    return parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/xml');
  };

  process.send('data', doc(html).select('span[blah..]').get(0).innerText);
});

process.send('ready', true);
```

Comment: Please see my edit, would your solution break the code i.e. is it like callback?

Comment: Yes, this makes it asynchronous. The idea is to do all of the DOM parsing and data retrieval in the forked process, and return only the data you need to the main process.

Comment: I just noticed that DOMParser is undefined on the server. What is the meteor way to parse html into dom on the server? Thx

Comment: You should probably Google it